# php form keeps giving me 500 error

Tags: php, html, forms, contact-form

I'm having trouble getting my contact form to work. I'm new to php and this is the first mailer I've created, so I could definitely use some help.

Here's my HTML form

```
        <form id="ajax-contact" method="post" action="mailer.php">
            <div class="column">
                <label for="name">name</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
                <label for="email">email address</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
            </div>

            <div class="column">
                <label for="message">message</label>
                <textarea id="message" required></textarea>
            </div>

            <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
```

Here's my mailer.php

```
<?php
    // My modifications to mailer script from:
    // http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-ajax-contact-form
    // Added input sanitizing to prevent injection


    // Only process POST reqeusts.
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
        $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
$name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
        $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $message = trim($_POST["message"]);


        // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
        if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
            http_response_code(400);
            echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
            exit;
        }


        $recipient = "thomas.lacroix.e@gmail.com";


        $subject = "New message from $name";


        $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
        $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
        $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";


        $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";


        // Send the email.
        if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
            // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
            http_response_code(200);
            echo "Thank You!";
        } else {
            // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
            http_response_code(500);
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong.";
        }


    } else {
        // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
        http_response_code(403);
        echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
    }
?>
```

I've searched for people with similar problems and I believe I need to add something with my email host settings. Let's be honest, though, I don't know what I'm doing. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Open the server logs and look what has caused the 500er error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like on your form you forgot to include the name for the textarea which is causing an undefined index in the code when trying to get

```
$_POST['message']
```

```
<textarea name="message" id="message" required></textarea>
```

Doing the above resolved the issue in testing for me.

Comment: Undefined index errors ("notice error") don't cause HTTP 500 Errors. Only Fatal Errors do that.

Comment: Yes, but it appears that the mail function doesn't like it and then fails and in his code if the mail function returns false, he has it set to output a 500 error.

Comment: Yes, but usually the webserver doesn't throw then a http 500 error, just the response code will be 500, but the response body would be the same as the output "Oops! Something went wrong". Nginx for example doesn't do this unless you tell him to interference on http errors.

Comment: You, my friend, are a wizard. I just needed 'name="message"'.

Comment: Ah, I get what you're saying. I do wonder if he's getting actual 500 errors then or just the 500 header and the output. Because you're right, of course it's not an actual 500 error. My access logs show a response code of 500 when testing, but of course no actual error in the error logs.

Comment: Yeah, take the specifics of what i said with a grain of salt. I'm not exactly an expert, so I may be wrong about it being a 500 error.

Comment: @Thomas no worries, we're all just here to help and just want to help in the best way we can and make sure we provide answers that work. :)